# how to calculate an average from a int2 array using Thrust

Tags: cuda, average, thrust

I'm trying to calculate the average of a certain array which contains points (x,y).
is it possible to use thrust to find the average point represented as a (x,y) point?
i could also represent the array as a `thrust::device_vector<int>`when each cell contains the absolute position of the point, meaning `i*numColumns + j` though I'm not sure that the average number represents the average cell.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just compute define an addition operator for the `int2` type (ie. `a+b={a.x+b.x,a.y+b.y}`), then use the standard reduction to compute the sum over the input, then divide through by the element count?

Comment: You can use an operator if you use Thrust 1.5+'s lambda placeholders (see my add-on answer below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

struct add_int2 {
  __device__
  int2 operator()(const int2& a, const int2& b) const {
    int2 r;
    r.x = a.x + b.x;
    r.y = a.y + b.y;
    return r;
  }
};

#define N 20

int main()
{
  thrust::host_vector<int2> a(N);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    a[i].x = i;
    a[i].y = i+1;
  }

  thrust::device_vector<int2> b = a;

  int2 init;
  init.x = init.y = 0;

  int2 ave = thrust::reduce(b.begin(), b.end(), init, add_int2());
  ave.x /= N;
  ave.y /= N;

  std::cout << ave.x << " " << ave.y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Keveman's answer is correct, I just want to add a useful tip which requires code, so I'll put it here rather than in the comments.

Thrust 1.5 adds lambda placeholders, which can make @keveman's approach even simpler.  Instead of a functor, just define `operator+` for `int2`, and then replace the instantiation of the functor with the `_1 + _2` lambda placeholder expression.  You can also replace the explicit declaration of `init` with a call to `make_int2()` (provided by CUDA).  Note: `int2 operator+` is defined in the CUDA code sample SDK's "vector_math.h" header, but I define it below to make it clear (since that file isn't a standard part of CUDA).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

__device__
int2 operator+(const int2& a, const int2& b) {
  return make_int2(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y);
}

#define N 20

int main()
{
  thrust::host_vector<int2> a(N);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    a[i].x = i;
    a[i].y = i+1;
  }

  thrust::device_vector<int2> b = a;

  int2 ave = thrust::reduce(b.begin(), b.end(), make_int2(0, 0), _1 + _2);
  ave.x /= N;
  ave.y /= N;

  std::cout << ave.x << " " << ave.y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```